# How to phrase the from field in system generated emails my site sends?

Tags: email, best-practices

I have a community site that sends emails after certain actions like

```
1) When someone makes a comment
2) When someone does something called "suggest solution"
3) When someone makes a comment in the suggested solution which is different from a regular comment.
```

What I am wondering is what is the best way to make the from field of the email appear?

Right now it is something like

```
1) comment@sitenmame.com
2) Suggestion.Solution@sitename.com
3) Suggestion.Comment@sitename.com
```

But 2 and 3 look so strange when receiving the email.  What is the nice and professional way to send these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send out the email you can include a display name associated with the email address. Different email clients display it in different ways, but they tend to use the display name first.

So if you send the email from

```
Sitename comment <comment@sitename.com>
```

then email clients will often just display

```
Sitename comment
```

in the inbox.

So you could use these for the other two

```
Sitename suggest solution <Suggestion.Solution@sitename.com>

Sitename suggest comment <suggestion.Comment@sitename.com>
```

Comment: Ah cool, thanks Paul. This is pretty standard way of doing this, right? Is there a way to make it more personal? Or that is just done in the body?  Any advice for phrasing the subject?

Comment: sometimes it is just from Sitename@sitename.com - when is a good time to use that? Twitter sends me emails that appear from twitter, but if I press reply, their email looks like: noreply@postmaster.twitter.com

Comment: Yes, that is a standard way of doing it. You could use the subject to make it more personal as joshuahedlund suggests.

Comment: What would a professional personal subject look like? Something like "Firstname Lastname, a message was posted on a topic you are following"  --- kind of long, no? Is there a better possible subject?

Comment: That doesn't look too long to me.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a singular `notification@sitename.com` to simplify management of different kinds of notifications? You can use the subject to specify the content, such as,

1. "User commented on your question"
2. "User suggested a solution to your question"
3. "User commented on your suggested solution"
   etc

Comment: yeah, but does that make it less engaging for users?

Comment: Good question, I don't have good data or sources to answer that, but my personal opinion is that a single email address and a personal subject is not less engaging (it may even be more consistent), and it seems to be the solution preferred (as you note) by sites like Twitter - although I'm not sure if it's a best practice used by similar major sites.